# DYLD, dependent dylib '@rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

My app crash with no description, but when I go Window/Devices and Simulators and open the log I can see this message:

> Termination Description: DYLD, dependent dylib
>   '@rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' not found for
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/SOMEID/Runner.app/Runner',
>   tried but didn't find: '/usr/lib/swift/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/SOMEID/Runner.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/SOMEID/Runner.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/SOMEID/Runner.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'
>   '@rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth'
>   '/System/Library/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth' Highlighted by
>   Thread:  0

I have Apple developer account so first I deleted some old certificates, because there are reports that Apple restricted the use of external frameworks to non paid devs, but it doesn't worked. Just in case revoked the certificates I had and leaved Xcode to automatically manage signing so it generated new ones but it doesn't worked too. I also removed the Podfile.lock did pod update, pod install just in case... still doesn't work.
Can anyone help me with this, please?

Edit: just to add I tried flutter clean too.

Comment: Would you please set **-ObjC** as other linker flag and try?

Comment: Already have it

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I also have it and I checked and the framework is there.